# How to make the dropdown preselect an option in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular

In the following example, the default value is correctly set, but the value is not selected by the dropdown when you open it. How to add a check for the option Two on init?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/p9encv

Currently when I open the dropdown, I see that:
[image]

But this is what I would like to see:
[image]

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly you want?

Comment: can you please provide additional details/screen shots indicating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there' a better way, but you can in opened event mark as selected the option

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (opened)="opened(auto)">
...
</mat-autocomplete>

  opened(autocomplete: MatAutocomplete)
  {
    //look for one option which "value" was the value of the FormControl
    const option=autocomplete.options.find(x=>x.value==this.myControl.value)

    //if exist and it's not selected
    if (option && !option.selected)
      option.select(true)
  }
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fu7rch?file=src%2Fmain.ts)